# Crawling Webpges using Webdriver or BOTS ike Scrapy and Requests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, phantomjs, python-requests

I am crawling a Product Website with several 10000's of items listed. When I use SCrapy I realized that It had to hit the POST call 50,000+ times which will result in blocking. If I use PhantomJs Webdriver here to automate the webpage actions, will it help? I mean is there any difference between how a Webkit like Selenium-PhantomJs and BOTS like Scrapy fetching data? Using Selenium can we prevent from being blocked? Any Suggestions please..

Comment: Are you talking about IO blocking or the site banning you?

Comment: It's about site, there is a chance to get blocked for more hits.

Comment: How about going slowly?

Answer (score 1):

If you need POST 50,000+ times to solve the problem by Scrapy ,you will cost more http requests by selenium and othes webkit like this.You need to find the rule which  will ban you.

Comment: Can't understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With selenium you can mimic more close to real human behaviour, but hitting 50000+ will not help with selenium either.

You have to use proxy, I suggest rotating proxies. After that you don't have to worry about getting banned after 50K requests.

Comment: I am using a Proxy already, there is only 1 though officially, you suggest to get more than 1?? Also in this case which is better Selenium or BOTS like Scrapy / Requests?

Comment: If you search as Rotating Proxies, you will see there are several of them. It is basically an ip and port, but on each request it assigns a different ip for you. So you get auto-rotated proxy. Selenium vs Scrapy maybe a deep subject, but I would go with the one I am comfortable with. Also if you use scrapy, use a rotation in user-agent as well.